# User have to press the gplay login btn twice

Tags: java, android, debugging, google-play, logcat

When Users click the google play login button, this circle appears:

[image]

a little moment later, the circle dissapears, and if the User presses the button again, this shows up, and the user is logged in:
[image]

How to do, that the user only have to press it once?